# Calling from C# to C function which accept a struct array allocated by caller

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have the following C struct

```
struct XYZ
{
void            *a;
char            fn[MAX_FN];     
unsigned long   l;          
unsigned long   o;  
};
```

And I want to call the following function from C#:

```
extern "C"  int     func(int handle, int *numEntries, XYZ *xyzTbl);
```

Where xyzTbl is an array of XYZ of size numEntires which is allocated by the caller

I have defined the following C# struct:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct XYZ
{
   public System.IntPtr rva;
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
   public string fn;
   public uint l;
   public uint o;
}
```

and a method:

```
 [DllImport(@"xyzdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Int32 func(Int32 handle, ref Int32 numntries,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] XYZ[] arr);
```

Then I try to call the function :

```
XYZ xyz = new XYZ[numEntries];
for (...) xyz[i] = new XYZ();
func(handle,numEntries,xyz);
```

Of course it does not work. Can someone shed light on what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: By the way, what's the error?

Comment: When calling `func` the second parameter needs a `ref` in front of it, since it is `ref` in the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct XYZ
{
   public System.IntPtr rva;
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
   public string fn;
   public uint l;
   public uint o;
}
```

Shouldn't those `uint` be `ulong` ? Also, MAX_FN is 128 right ?

```
XYZ xyz = new XYZ[numEntries];
for (...) xyz[i] = new XYZ();
```

XYZ is a value type (struct), so the second line here is redundant (structs are always initialized)

```
 [DllImport(@"xyzdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern Int32 func(Int32 handle, ref Int32 numntries,
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] XYZ[] arr);
```

`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]` is redundant, the compiler will see it's a struct array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use `LPArray` when you have a managed structure. Just take that out, and use `[In]` and `[Out]` (if needed) instead.

IIRC, if you use `LPArray`, that would try to pass a pointer to the first element, which is illegal because the structure isn't blittable. You'd need to remove the `[MarshalAs(...)]` entirely.

---

Edit:

I don't remember, but you might need to initialize the string fields before passing them... I'll check that when I get the chance.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but it does not work. I think that Marshalling is required since C# and C++ represent arrays differently. Can I create C# array as  contigious block of structs ?

Comment: @lifey: Hm... what is the error you get? Knowing that would really help. And yes, marshaling *does* need to happen, it's just that I don't think you specify it explicitly as `LPArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: [Marshal C++ struct array into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188299/marshal-c-struct-array-into-c) , probably it would help.

Comment: Thanks Nickolay the post you are talking about is different. I need to allocate the struct array in C#....

Comment: Yes, actually. I also found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor1, MSDN tells that you should (probably) also pass SizeConst parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would marshal this manually. First, make xyzTbl an `IntPtr`.

```
[DllImport(@"xyzdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 func(Int32 handle, ref Int32 numntries, IntPtr xyzTb);
```

Rather than allocating the XYZ array like you are doing - allocate enough unmanaged memory to store the table.

```
IntPtr unmanaged = 
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(XYZ)) * numEntries);
```

Call your `func(handle, ref numEntries, unmanaged);` The job then is to unmarshal the unmanaged memory back into managed types.

```
IntPtr[] entries = new IntPtr[numEntries];
List<XYZ> xyz = new List<XYZ>();
Marshal.Copy(unmanaged, entries, 0, numEntries);
foreach (IntPtr entry in entries)
    xyz.Add(Marshal.PtrToStructure(entry, typeof(XYZ)));

Marsha.FreeHGlobal(unmanaged);
```

Comment: This kind of manual marshalling is only necessary if the unmanaged code keeps a reference to the memory passed in beyond the point where the called function returns.

Comment: And your finalization code isn't very robust either. But most likely that only matters in few applications. Typically those that require clean unloads of AppDomains.