# Return allocated value from Unmanaged code to managed

Tags: c#, c

I would like to do the following:
Call Unamanaged method that returns the array of type MyStruct[] that it allocated.

Example of c code:

```
MyStruct[] foo(int size)
{
   Mystruct* st = (MyStruct*)malloc(size * sizeof(MyStruct));
   return st;
}
```

How should Implement c# calling method?

Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to use existing algorithm written in unmanaged.dll and want to get the result :)

Comment: That code doesn't do anything useful.  Might as well use Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem().

Comment: :) This is the sample of code that was not clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace has a lot of methods to help you marshal data to and from unmanaged code.

You need to declare your native method:

```
[DllImport("myclib.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr Foo(Int32 size);
```

And also your C struct as a managed value type (you can use attributes on the fields to control exactly how they are mapped to native memory when they are marshalled):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MyStruct {
  public Char Character;
  public Int32 Number;
}
```

Then you can use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to marshal each element of the array into a managed value:

```
var n = 12;
var pointer = Foo(n);
var array = new MyStruct[n];
var structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  array[i] = (MyStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(MyStruct));
  pointer += structSize;
}
```

Note that you are using `malloc` to allocate the memory in the C code. C# us unable to free that memory and you will have to provide another method to free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Read that I haven't found  there how to return array type of meclared struct

Comment: Its no direct solution,work around could be to pass the array and let the library fill it and send it back. As explained here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/132083/returning-a-byte-array-from-objc-to-c-script-on-io.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188299/marshal-c-struct-array-into-c), it has some information about how to return a dynamically allocated struct from C++ to C# as an array.