# Marshal array of struct from c++ dll to c#

Tags: c#

I want to return array of struct from the C++ dll to c#. I am trying it as following:

In c++ code:

```
 Vertex*
GetVertices(Vertex* vertices, float aPos, int& vSize) {
     if ( !plane ) {
        plane = new ClipPlane;
        plane->type = PlaneType;
    }
     Vertex* v = plane->mesh->vertex;
     vSize = plane->mesh->size*3;
     vertices = v;

     return vertices;
}
```

and exported it in c++ like `Some_API Vertex* GetVertices(Vertex*, float, int &);`

and on C# side:

```
[DllImport("some.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetVertices(Vertex[] vertices, float aPos, ref int vSize);
```

and calling it like:

```
GetMeshSize(x_value, ref vSize);
            Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[vSize];
            GetVertices(vertices, x_value, ref vSize);
```

Forget about the vSize and x_value for time being. My problem is I am not able to get the values of vertices in c#, I just want to know that how do I marshal array of the struct Vertex in c#. Note that I dont know anything about Marshal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188299/marshal-c-struct-array-into-c-sharp

Comment: i am visiting after a long time but anyways thnx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marshal C++ struct array into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188299/marshal-c-struct-array-into-c-sharp)